# Groovy: Add some element of list to another list

Tags: groovy

```
list1 = [[1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'],[2,'Jack','Jo','Raj','Giri'],[...]....]

list2 = [['20 May 2013',20],['25 May 2013',26],[...]....]
```

there will be 100 of such records

i want the resulting list like

```
list1 = [[1, '20 May 2013', 20, 'Rob','Ben','Ni', 'cool'],[2,'25 May 2013', 26, 'Jack','Jo','Raj','Giri']]
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: See my update for the answer. I hope there will be no more edit to the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[list1, list2].transpose()*.flatten()
```

Assuming cardinality of `list1` and `list2` is same.

**UPDATE**
Question is modified drastically now, but you can get what you seek by extending the transpose  as below:

```
[list1, list2].transpose()*.flatten()
                           .collect{[it[0], it[-2..-1], it[1..-3]]}*.flatten()
```

Comment: Just when I think I've made code as concise as possible, @dmahapatro or Tim Yates posts an answer...

Comment: @BDKosher LOL. I say the same to Tim when he does that. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def i = 0
def combined = list1.collect([]) { it + list2[i++] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The result row isn't the concatenation of the two list rows - it takes the second row and inserts it into index 1 of the first row, without the last two elements. So

`[list1, list2].transpose()*.flatten()`

won't work - tho' it is pretty cool :-). However,

`[list1,list2].transpose().collect { def l = it.flatten(); l[0..0] + l[5..6] + l[1..2] }`

gives the result show  in the question. And I fully admit to standing on the backs of giants :-)