# Groovy : Create new list out of two list

Tags: groovy

I am groovy beginner

I have two lists

```
    ​list1 = [[1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'],[2,'Jack','Jo','Raj','Giri']....[]...] 

   list2 = [[null,'2013-10-09','2013-10-10'],[4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12']]
```

i want to combine these lists in following format

```
 list3  = [[1, null, '2013-10-09', '2013-10-10', 'Rob', 'Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], [2, 4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12', 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri']]
```

tried [Groovy: Add some element of list to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182637/groovy-add-some-element-of-list-to-another-list/19191738?noredirect=1#19191738)

but couldn't do in this format.. help me!

Comment: FYI. Modifying to `[it[0], it[-3..-1], it[1..-4]]` inside collect [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19182756/2051952) will give you the same result although I vouch for Will P's answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `collect` the `head()`, `pop()` and `tail()`:

```
def list1 = [ [1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], [2, 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri'] ]

def list2 = [ [null,'2013-10-09','2013-10-10'],[4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12'] ]

def stack = list2.reverse()

def list3 = list1.collect { l1 -> 
    [l1.head()] + stack.pop() + l1.tail()
}

assert list3 == [
  [1, null, '2013-10-09', '2013-10-10', 'Rob', 'Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], 
  [2,4,'2013-10-11', '2013-10-12', 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri']
]
```

Comment: Niceeeee. When I picturize the operation inside `collect` it reminds me of Minority Report. ;)

Comment: BTW, `flatten()` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

```
[list1, list2].transpose().collect { [it[0][0]] + it[1] + it[0][1..-1] }
```

will do what you need but isn't particularly efficient as it creates and then throws away many intermediate lists.  The more efficient approach would be good old fashioned direct iteration:

```
def list3 = []
def it1 = list1.iterator()
def it2 = list2.iterator()
while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
  def l1 = it1.next()
  def l2 = it2.next()
  def l = [l1[0]]
  l.addAll(l2)
  l.addAll(l1[1..-1])
  list3 << l
}
```

which is rather less Groovy but creates far fewer throwaway lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (clearly needs some defensive checks regarding matching sizes of list1, list2, empty lists, etc):

```
def list1 = [[1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'],[2,'Jack','Jo','Raj','Giri']] 
def list2 = [[null,'2013-10-09','2013-10-10'],[4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12']]

def newList = []

list1.eachWithIndex { def subList1, def index ->
    def tmpList = []
    tmpList << subList1[0]
    tmpList.addAll(list2[index])
    tmpList.addAll(subList1[1..subList1.size()-1])
    newList << tmpList
}

def list3  = [[1, null, '2013-10-09', '2013-10-10', 'Rob', 'Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], [2,4,'2013-10-11', '2013-10-12', 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri']]

assert newList == list3
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Will P's answer more, but here's an alternative:

```
def list1 = [ [1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], [2, 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri'] ]

def list2 = [ [null,'2013-10-09','2013-10-10'],[4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12'] ]

def list3 = []
list1.eachWithIndex { one, i -> list3 << [one[0]] + list2[i] + one[1..-1] }

assert list3 == [
  [1, null, '2013-10-09', '2013-10-10', 'Rob', 'Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'], 
  [2, 4,'2013-10-11', '2013-10-12', 'Jack', 'Jo', 'Raj', 'Giri']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
​list1 = [[1,'Rob','Ben', 'Ni', 'cool'],[2,'Jack','Jo','Raj','Giri']....[]...] 
list2 = [[null,'2013-10-09','2013-10-10'],[4, '2013-10-11', '2013-10-12']]

def list3 = []
list3.addAll(list1)
list3.addAll(list2)
```

Comment: i want to add all element of list2 after index 0 of first list